# how to create non root account on Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have some packages from Ubuntu that cannot be installed as root account which is the default on Colab.

I have tried the following:

- !sudo useradd -m ted
- !passwd ted (set the new password)
- !su ted

This generates an error:
sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off

I am not a linux person so I am not sure what does that mean.

Comment: What is the package that you are attempting to install?

Comment: It's related to gem bundler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385493/how-to-run-bundle-install-as-normal-user

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to use `!` in google colab.

Add a newuser:

```
adduser username 
usermod -aG sudo username
```

Switch user:

```
su username
```

Installing package:

```
sudo -S apt install pkg_name
```

Comment: On the adduser command, the colab just stalls and does not continue after 'Adding new user `username' (1000) with group `username' ...'

Comment: Instead I did:

! sudo useradd -m username

! sudo adduser username sudo

Comment: The username is not persisting beyond the cell where use the !su <newuser> command. In the next cell, !whoami shows that user is back to root. How to make it persist?

Answer (score 1):

You just can type the command without the sudo part like this `!adduser ted`and it will work
Then switch to the new user by `!su ted` then a textbox will appear in it u can write your commands

Answer (score 0):

I just used the commands `!adduser username` and then `!su username`.

Also type in the commands in the prompt you get after doing this (not in the new notebook cell).